# Call a method on a new object from a variable

Tags: python, oop, higher-order-functions

I have a class containing a list and some boolean methods.

```
class Cls:
    data = [] // populated in __init__()


    def flag1(self):
    def flag2(self):
    def flag3(self): # these all return booleans, based on the data
```

I want to create a higher level function, taking a parameter one of the flags, manipulating the data in a number of ways, applying the flag to the new data, and counting the number of results.

Something like:

```
def hof(self, fn):
  count = 0
  for i in range(1, 10):
    new_obj = Cls(self.data+i)
    if new_obj.fn():
      count +=1
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without turning all the flags into static methods ?

===
Edit: Made it work, in a very hackish way:

```
class Cls:
  data = []
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = value
  class flag1(self):
    return True
  class flag2(self):
    return False

  # The hackish part
  flag_dict = {
    1: flag1,
    2: flag2,
  }
  def hof(self, flag):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,10):
      new_obj = Cls(self.data + [i])
      if self.flag_dict[flag](new_obj):
        count +=1
    return count
```

But it seems like a hack, and it's not quite understandable. Could someone point to a better way ?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened? While I'm here, when you say the class-level mutable variable is "populated" in `__init__()`, do you mean "replaced with the desired value" in which case it should probably have a different default, or "mutated to contain the desired value", in which case every instance will have the same data?

Comment: @mwchase , I just meant something like `def __init__(self, value): self.data=value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just pass the methods into the function like `instance.hof(Cls.flag1)`, and internally, write it as `if fn(new_obj):`, with no need to make it a staticmethod.